# How can I change the output display in lightning app of sales force other than table?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created lwc for my custom object and I used lightning datatable for viewing it. Unfortunately I have lot of fields and hence, I would like to change the type of view. I tried using lightning list or tabs and it is not working. Please find the attached output.

Javascript

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import Case from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Case_Statement__c';
import CONSULTANT_REVENUE from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Consultant_Salary__c';
import CONSULTANT_DAYS from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Consultant_Summary__c';
import CONSULTANT_ESTIMATION from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Consultant_Estimation__c';
import DEVELOPER_REVENUE from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Developer_Salary__c';
import DEVELOPER_DAYS from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Developer_Summary__c';
import DEVELOPER_ESTIMATION from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Developer_Estimation__c';
import SENIOR_CONSULTANT_REVENUE from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Senior_Consultant_Salary__c';
import SENIOR_CONSULTANT_DAYS from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Senior_Consultant_Summary__c';
import SENIOR_CONSULTANT_ESTIMATION from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Senior_Consultant_Estimation__c';
import SENIOR_DEVELOPER_REVENUE from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Senior_Developer_Salary__c';
import SENIOR_DEVELOPER_DAYS from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Senior_Developer_Summary__c';
import SENIOR_DEVELOPER_ESTIMATION from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Senior_Developer_Estimation__c';
import PERSONAL_MANAGER_REVENUE from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Personal_Manager__c';
import PERSONAL_MANAGER_DAYS from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Personal_Manager_Summary__c';
import PERSONAL_MANAGER_ESTIMATION from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Personal_Manager_Estimation__c';
import TOTAL_ESTIMATION from '@salesforce/schema/Request_for_proposal__c.Total_Estimation__c';
import getrfp from '@salesforce/apex/Estimationcontroller.getrfp';
const COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'Case Statement', fieldName: Case.fieldApiName, type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Consultant Revenue', fieldName: CONSULTANT_REVENUE.fieldApiName, type: 'currency'},
    { label: 'Consultant (Estimation of Days)', ffieldName: CONSULTANT_DAYS.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Consultant (Estimation of Total Revenue)', ffieldName: CONSULTANT_ESTIMATION.fieldApiName, type: 'currency' },
    {label: 'Developer Revenue', fieldName: DEVELOPER_REVENUE.fieldApiName, type: 'currency'},
    { label: 'Developer (Estimation of Days)', ffieldName: DEVELOPER_DAYS.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Developer (Estimation of Total Revenue)', ffieldName: DEVELOPER_ESTIMATION.fieldApiName, type: 'currency' },
    {label: 'Senior Consultant Revenue', fieldName: SENIOR_CONSULTANT_REVENUE.fieldApiName, type: 'currency'},
    { label: 'Senior Consultant (Estimation of Days)', ffieldName: SENIOR_CONSULTANT_DAYS.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Senior Consultant (Estimation of Total Revenue)', ffieldName: SENIOR_CONSULTANT_ESTIMATION.fieldApiName, type: 'currency' },
    {label: 'Senior Developer Revenue', fieldName: SENIOR_DEVELOPER_REVENUE.fieldApiName, type: 'currency'},
    { label: 'Senior Developer (Estimation of Days)', ffieldName: SENIOR_DEVELOPER_DAYS.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Senior Developer (Estimation of Total Revenue)', ffieldName: SENIOR_DEVELOPER_ESTIMATION.fieldApiName, type: 'currency' },
    {label: 'Personal Manager Revenue', fieldName: PERSONAL_MANAGER_REVENUE.fieldApiName, type: 'currency'},
    { label: 'Personal Manager (Estimation of Days)', ffieldName: PERSONAL_MANAGER_DAYS.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Personal (Estimation of Total Revenue)', ffieldName: PERSONAL_MANAGER_ESTIMATION.fieldApiName, type: 'currency' },
    { label: 'Overall (Estimation of Total Revenue)', ffieldName: TOTAL_ESTIMATION.fieldApiName, type: 'currency' }
];
export default class Requests extends LightningElement {
    columns = COLUMNS;
    @wire(getrfp)
    requests;
}
```

HTML

```
template>
    <lightning-card>
        <template if:true={requests.data}>
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Name"
                data={requests.data}
                columns={columns}
            >
           </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Markup language

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Please find the attached output. When I combined all the lwc components together, it did not look good. Could you all suggest me a layout?.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  use [lightning-layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout/example) and [lightning-layout-item](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/example) with specifying `size` of each `layout-item` on the parent component, where those 3 datatables should be rendered.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
            <lightning-layout-item size="6">
                <c-datatable1></c-datatable1>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="6">
                <c-datatable2></c-datatable2>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="6">
                <c-datatable3></c-datatable3>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give it a try.

Comment: I think I will go for lightning layout. Table is too small for my data.

Comment: Okay , I accepted it :).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using custom tables. I used lightning input and output fields. For example, instead of table in categories,

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-layout horizontal-align="spread" multiple-rows>
            <lightning-record-view-form record-id= {recordId} object-api-name="Categories__c">
                <p style="color:blue;">Categories</p>
                <div class="slds-box slds-theme\_default">
            <lightning-layout-item size= 6 >
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Consultant_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Developer_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Senior_Developer_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Senior_Consultant_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Personal_Manager_Summary__c"></lightning-output-field> 
           </lightning-layout-item>
           </div>
            </lightning-record-view-form>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

I used this code and the output was looking like,
[image: output]

This was pretty neat.